# is there an easy way to return a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a properties file that I am reading and converting it into a dictionary using json library in python "convertedDict = json.loads(properties)" :

```
[
{"a":"1"},
{"b":"2"},
{"c":"3"},
{"d":"4"},
{"e":"5"},
{"f":"6"}
]
```

I want to have an output returned like below, which I want to be dictionaries inside of a list. I also want to add the words "key" and "value" in the dictionaries:

```
[
        {
            "key": "a",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "key": "b",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "key": "c",
            "value": "3"
        },
        {
            "key": "d",
            "value": "4"
        },
        {
            "key": "e",
            "value": "5"
        },
        {
            "key": "f",
            "value": "6"
        }
]
```

Please advise if you know, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple list comprehension and create the dictionaries in that.  Here's one way to do it:

```
l = [
  {"a":"1"},
  {"b":"2"},
  {"c":"3"},
  {"d":"4"},
  {"e":"5"},
  {"f":"6"}
]

[{"key":k, "value":v} for d in l for k, v in d.items()]
```

Which results in:

```
[{'key': 'a', 'value': '1'},
 {'key': 'b', 'value': '2'},
 {'key': 'c', 'value': '3'},
 {'key': 'd', 'value': '4'},
 {'key': 'e', 'value': '5'},
 {'key': 'f', 'value': '6'}]
```